# How to keep fields from being sent in Swift mailer?

Tags: javascript, php, swiftmailer

I am using Swift mailer to send a form to an email but it is sending the google captcha code on the email.

All the fields I put in are being sent to the email, but some are unnecessary. I don't need the captcha code to appear in the email. How do I keep it from being sent?

I am not a php developer and kinda new to java script

```
<form class="form-signup" data-success="Thanks for your submission, we will be in touch shortly." 
      data-error="Please fill all fields correctly."
    <input type="text" class="validate-required" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">

    <input type="text" class="validate-required" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">

    <input type="text" class="validate-required validate-email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">

    <input type="text" class="validate-required" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">

    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8" style="z-index: 200">

        <div><span style="font-weight: 600;">WERE YOU REFFERED TO US?</span></div>
        <div class="radios" style="padding-left: 70px;">
            <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-1" checked>
            <label for="radio-1"><span class="radio" style="font-weight: 600;">NO</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="radios" style="padding-left: 70px;">
            <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-2">
            <label for="radio-2"><span class="radio" style="font-weight: 600;">YES</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="prepend"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key" style=" text-align: right;"></div>
    </div>
    <input id="affiliate" type="text" class="" name="affiliate" placeholder="Affiliate Number">

    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">

</form>
```

Contact form code

```
    $('form.form-signup').submit(function(e) {

        // return false so form submits through jQuery rather than reloading page.
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        else e.returnValue = false;

        var thisForm = $(this).closest('form.form-signup'),
            error = 0,
            originalError = thisForm.attr('original-error'),
            loadingSpinner, iFrame, userEmail, userFullName, userFirstName, userLastName, successRedirect;

        // Mailchimp/Campaign Monitor Mail List Form Scripts
        iFrame = $(thisForm).find('iframe.mail-list-form');

        thisForm.find('.form-error, .form-success').remove();
        thisForm.append('<div class="form-error" style="display: none;">' + thisForm.attr('data-error') + '</div>');
        thisForm.append('<div class="form-success" style="display: none;">' + thisForm.attr('data-success') + '</div>');


        if ((iFrame.length) && (typeof iFrame.attr('srcdoc') !== "undefined") && (iFrame.attr('srcdoc') !== "")) {

            console.log('Mail list form signup detected.');
            userEmail = $(thisForm).find('.signup-email-field').val();
            userFullName = $(thisForm).find('.signup-name-field').val();
            if ($(thisForm).find('input.signup-first-name-field').length) {
                userFirstName = $(thisForm).find('input.signup-first-name-field').val();
            } else {
                userFirstName = $(thisForm).find('.signup-name-field').val();
            }
            userLastName = $(thisForm).find('.signup-last-name-field').val();

            // validateFields returns 1 on error;
            if (validateFields(thisForm) !== 1) {
                console.log('Mail list signup form validation passed.');
                console.log(userEmail);
                console.log(userLastName);
                console.log(userFirstName);
                console.log(userFullName);

                iFrame.contents().find('#mce-EMAIL, #fieldEmail').val(userEmail);
                iFrame.contents().find('#mce-LNAME, #fieldLastName').val(userLastName);
                iFrame.contents().find('#mce-FNAME, #fieldFirstName').val(userFirstName);
                iFrame.contents().find('#mce-NAME, #fieldName').val(userFullName);
                iFrame.contents().find('form').attr('target', '_blank').submit();
                successRedirect = thisForm.attr('success-redirect');
                // For some browsers, if empty `successRedirect` is undefined; for others,
                // `successRedirect` is false.  Check for both.
                if (typeof successRedirect !== typeof undefined && successRedirect !== false && successRedirect !== "") {
                    window.location = successRedirect;
                }
            } else {
                thisForm.find('.form-error').fadeIn(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    thisForm.find('.form-error').fadeOut(500);
                }, 5000);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Send email form detected.');
            if (typeof originalError !== typeof undefined && originalError !== false) {
                thisForm.find('.form-error').text(originalError);
            }


            error = validateFields(thisForm);


            if (error === 1) {
                $(this).closest('form').find('.form-error').fadeIn(200);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(thisForm).find('.form-error').fadeOut(500);
                }, 3000);
            } else {
                // Hide the error if one was shown
                $(this).closest('form').find('.form-error').fadeOut(200);
                // Create a new loading spinner while hiding the submit button.
                loadingSpinner = jQuery('<div />').addClass('form-loading').insertAfter($(thisForm).find('input[type="submit"]'));
                $(thisForm).find('input[type="submit"]').hide();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "mail/mail-signup.php",
                    data: thisForm.serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Swiftmailer always sends back a number representing numner of emails sent.
                        // If this is numeric (not Swift Mailer error text) AND greater than 0 then show success message.
                        $(thisForm).find('.form-loading').remove();

                        $(thisForm).find('input[type="submit"]').show();
                        if ($.isNumeric(response)) {
                            if (parseInt(response) > 0) {
                                // For some browsers, if empty 'successRedirect' is undefined; for others,
                                // 'successRedirect' is false.  Check for both.
                                successRedirect = thisForm.attr('success-redirect');
                                if (typeof successRedirect !== typeof undefined && successRedirect !== false && successRedirect !== "") {
                                    window.location = successRedirect;
                                }
                                thisForm.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
                                thisForm.find('textarea').val("");
                                thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeIn(1000);

                                thisForm.find('.form-error').fadeOut(1000);
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeOut(500);
                                }, 5000);
                            }
                        }
                        // If error text was returned, put the text in the .form-error div and show it.
                        else {
                            // Keep the current error text in a data attribute on the form
                            thisForm.find('.form-error').attr('original-error', thisForm.find('.form-error').text());
                            // Show the error with the returned error text.
                            thisForm.find('.form-error').text(response).fadeIn(1000);
                            thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeOut(1000);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(errorObject, errorText, errorHTTP) {
                        // Keep the current error text in a data attribute on the form
                        thisForm.find('.form-error').attr('original-error', thisForm.find('.form-error').text());
                        // Show the error with the returned error text.
                        thisForm.find('.form-error').text(errorHTTP).fadeIn(1000);
                        thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeOut(1000);
                        $(thisForm).find('.form-loading').remove();
                        $(thisForm).find('input[type="submit"]').show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return false;
    });



    //end if//

    $('form.form-email, form.form-newsletter').submit(function(e) {

        // return false so form submits through jQuery rather than reloading page.
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        else e.returnValue = false;

        var thisForm = $(this).closest('form.form-email, form.form-newsletter'),
            error = 0,
            originalError = thisForm.attr('original-error'),
            loadingSpinner, iFrame, userEmail, userFullName, userFirstName, userLastName, successRedirect;

        // Mailchimp/Campaign Monitor Mail List Form Scripts
        iFrame = $(thisForm).find('iframe.mail-list-form');

        thisForm.find('.form-error, .form-success').remove();
        thisForm.append('<div class="form-error" style="display: none;">' + thisForm.attr('data-error') + '</div>');
        thisForm.append('<div class="form-success" style="display: none;">' + thisForm.attr('data-success') + '</div>');


        if ((iFrame.length) && (typeof iFrame.attr('srcdoc') !== "undefined") && (iFrame.attr('srcdoc') !== "")) {

            console.log('Mail list form signup detected.');
            userEmail = $(thisForm).find('.signup-email-field').val();
            userFullName = $(thisForm).find('.signup-name-field').val();
            if ($(thisForm).find('input.signup-first-name-field').length) {
                userFirstName = $(thisForm).find('input.signup-first-name-field').val();
            } else {
                userFirstName = $(thisForm).find('.signup-name-field').val();
            }
            userLastName = $(thisForm).find('.signup-last-name-field').val();

            // validateFields returns 1 on error;
            if (validateFields(thisForm) !== 1) {
                console.log('Mail list signup form validation passed.');
                console.log(userEmail);
                console.log(userLastName);
                console.log(userFirstName);
                console.log(userFullName);

                iFrame.contents().find('#mce-EMAIL, #fieldEmail').val(userEmail);
                iFrame.contents().find('#mce-LNAME, #fieldLastName').val(userLastName);
                iFrame.contents().find('#mce-FNAME, #fieldFirstName').val(userFirstName);
                iFrame.contents().find('#mce-NAME, #fieldName').val(userFullName);
                iFrame.contents().find('form').attr('target', '_blank').submit();
                successRedirect = thisForm.attr('success-redirect');
                // For some browsers, if empty `successRedirect` is undefined; for others,
                // `successRedirect` is false.  Check for both.
                if (typeof successRedirect !== typeof undefined && successRedirect !== false && successRedirect !== "") {
                    window.location = successRedirect;
                }
            } else {
                thisForm.find('.form-error').fadeIn(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    thisForm.find('.form-error').fadeOut(500);
                }, 5000);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Send email form detected.');
            if (typeof originalError !== typeof undefined && originalError !== false) {
                thisForm.find('.form-error').text(originalError);
            }


            error = validateFields(thisForm);


            if (error === 1) {
                $(this).closest('form').find('.form-error').fadeIn(200);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(thisForm).find('.form-error').fadeOut(500);
                }, 3000);
            } else {
                // Hide the error if one was shown
                $(this).closest('form').find('.form-error').fadeOut(200);
                // Create a new loading spinner while hiding the submit button.
                loadingSpinner = jQuery('<div />').addClass('form-loading').insertAfter($(thisForm).find('input[type="submit"]'));
                $(thisForm).find('input[type="submit"]').hide();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "mail/mail.php",
                    data: thisForm.serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Swiftmailer always sends back a number representing numner of emails sent.
                        // If this is numeric (not Swift Mailer error text) AND greater than 0 then show success message.
                        $(thisForm).find('.form-loading').remove();

                        $(thisForm).find('input[type="submit"]').show();
                        if ($.isNumeric(response)) {
                            if (parseInt(response) > 0) {
                                // For some browsers, if empty 'successRedirect' is undefined; for others,
                                // 'successRedirect' is false.  Check for both.
                                successRedirect = thisForm.attr('success-redirect');
                                if (typeof successRedirect !== typeof undefined && successRedirect !== false && successRedirect !== "") {
                                    window.location = successRedirect;
                                }
                                thisForm.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
                                thisForm.find('textarea').val("");
                                thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeIn(1000);

                                thisForm.find('.form-error').fadeOut(1000);
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeOut(500);
                                }, 5000);
                            }
                        }
                        // If error text was returned, put the text in the .form-error div and show it.
                        else {
                            // Keep the current error text in a data attribute on the form
                            thisForm.find('.form-error').attr('original-error', thisForm.find('.form-error').text());
                            // Show the error with the returned error text.
                            thisForm.find('.form-error').text(response).fadeIn(1000);
                            thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeOut(1000);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(errorObject, errorText, errorHTTP) {
                        // Keep the current error text in a data attribute on the form
                        thisForm.find('.form-error').attr('original-error', thisForm.find('.form-error').text());
                        // Show the error with the returned error text.
                        thisForm.find('.form-error').text(errorHTTP).fadeIn(1000);
                        thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeOut(1000);
                        $(thisForm).find('.form-loading').remove();
                        $(thisForm).find('input[type="submit"]').show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return false;
    });






    $('.validate-required, .validate-email').on('blur change', function() {
        validateFields($(this).closest('form'));
    });

    $('form').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('.form-error').length) {
            $(this).attr('original-error', $(this).find('.form-error').text());
        }
    });

    function validateFields(form) {
            var name, error, originalErrorMessage;

            $(form).find('.validate-required[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                if (!$('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]:checked').length) {
                    error = 1;
                    name = $(this).attr('name').replace('[]', '');
                    form.find('.form-error').text('Please tick at least one ' + name + ' box.');
                }
            });

            $(form).find('.validate-required').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() === '') {
                    $(this).addClass('field-error');
                    error = 1;
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('field-error');
                }
            });

            $(form).find('.validate-email').each(function() {
                if (!(/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test($(this).val()))) {
                    $(this).addClass('field-error');
                    error = 1;
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('field-error');
                }
            });

            if (!form.find('.field-error').length) {
                form.find('.form-error').fadeOut(1000);
            }

            return error;
        }
        // End contact form code
```

php

```
 <?php
    $email;$comment;$captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
      $email=$_POST['email'];
    }if(isset($_POST['first-name'])){
      $email=$_POST['first-name'];
    }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo 'Please check the captcha form.';
      exit;
    }
    $secretKey = "key";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
    if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
      echo 'Something went wrog. It looks like Google recconized you as a robot. Come back later and try again.';
    } else {





    $emailMethod                = 'phpmail'; // REQUIRED value. Options: 'smtp' , 'phpmail'

    // Outgoing Server Settings - replace values on the right of the = sign with your own.
    // These 3 settings are only required if you choose 'smtp' for emailMethod above.
    $outgoingServerAddress      = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Consult your hosting provider.
    $outgoingServerPort         = '587';                  // Options: '587' , '25' - Consult your hosting provider.
    $outgoingServerSecurity     = 'tls';                 // Options: 'ssl' , 'tls' , null - Consult your hosting provider.

    // Sending Account Settings - replace these details with an email account held on the SMTP server entered above.
    // These 2 settings are only required if you choose 'smtp' for emailMethod above.
    $sendingAccountUsername     = 'email';
    $sendingAccountPassword     = 'pass';

    // Recipient (To:) Details  - Change this to the email details of who will receive all the emails from the website.
    $recipientEmail             = 'email'; // REQUIRED value.
    $recipientName              = 'recip';             // REQUIRED value.

    // Email details            - Change these to suit your website needs
    $emailSubject               = 'Sign Up Form'; // REQUIRED value. Subject of the email that the recipient will see
    $websiteName                = 'name';                // REQUIRED value. This is used when a name or email is not collected from the website form

    $timeZone                   = 'U.S/Salt Lake City';         // OPTIONAL, but some servers require this to be set. 
                                                                 // See a list of all supported timezones at: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
     /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
    |*  You do not need to edit anything below this line, the rest is automatic.    *|
     \*============================================================================*/

    include('lib/mail_sender.php');
            }
                ?>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: SwiftMailer is a library of files. I am not sure which part to post.

Comment: you post the part that you wrote that uses `swiftmailer`

Comment: you have added your `html` you need to add the backend `php` that this is posted to.